# Azure Data Lake .Net SDK Concat Files without removing files

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

Is there any way to concat files in data lake store with .net sdk for azure data lake store, that not delete from data lake files that i want to concat (merge) in one file? I'm searched in documentation but currently I couldn't find any method that not remove files after concat it in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Data Lake Store does not support such an operation today. Concatenating files while keeping the source files intact amounts to copying the data, which is not currently supported as a built-in operation by Data Lake Store.

If you'd like to concatenate files and keep the source files intact, I recommend running the [ADLCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob#use-adlcopy-as-standalone-to-copy-data-from-another-data-lake-store-account) client to **copy** the source files into a separate/new folder, then run the `Concat` or `MsConcat` operation to destructively concatenate the new copy of the source files, not touching the original source files.